# HTML DOM table removing/deleting selected row/rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I have the following code.
I am trying to include a delete button to delete the selected row or rows... in the code the selection is included and also the delete function but I can't figure how to get the selected row and pass it to the function to remove it... 
One button which is included in the code should be enough but if you know how to include a delete button "X" in every row then please tell me...

Here is the example page: 
http://knightfire66.bplaced.net/testcode.php
and here are some other codes but it does not work with my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z22NU/12/

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Test code</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3cschool.cc/try/jeasyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.w3cschool.cc/try/jeasyui/themes/icon.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.w3cschool.cc/try/jeasyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var pricelist = new Map({Name: 1, Preis: 2});
        pricelist.set("Balloon", 25);
    var ddamount = new Map({Name: 1, amount: 2});
        ddamount.set("Balloon", 1);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .products{
            list-style:none;
            margin-right:300px;
            padding:0px;
            height:100%;
        }
        .products li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }
        .item{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }
        .cart{
            position:fixed;
            right:0;
            top:0;
            width:300px;
            height:100%;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:0px 10px;
        }
        h1{
            text-align:center;
            color:#555;
        }
        h2{
            position:absolute;
            font-size:16px;
            left:10px;
            bottom:20px;
            color:#555;
        }
        .total{
            margin:0;
            text-align:right;
            padding-right:20px;
        }
        th {
            border: 1px #DDD solid; 
            padding: 5px; 
            cursor: pointer;}
        .selected {
            background-color: brown;
            color: #FFF;
        }
    </style>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <script>
        var data = {"total":0,"rows":[]};
        var totalCost = 0;
        var name;
        var amount;
        var price;

//DragDropFunction
        $(function(){
            $('#cart').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true //here with false i can select more then 1
            });
            $('.item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });
            $('.cart').droppable({
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(ddamount.get(name))); //parseFloat(price.split('€')[1])
                }
            });
        });

        function addProduct(name, amount){
            amount = parseFloat(amount);
            price = pricelist.get(name);
            price = amount*price;
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += amount;
                        row.price += price;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:amount, //statt amount
                    price:price
                });
            }
            add();
            totalCost += price;
            $('#cart').datagrid('loadData', data);
            $('div.cart .total').html('Total: â‚¬'+totalCost);
        }

//HERE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        function deleteRow(r) {
            var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("cart").deleteRow(i); //instead of i i want the selected row/or rows.. i can select more thn one
    </script>
</head>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;background:#fafafa;">
    <ul class="products">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item"> <!-- class ist Pflicht -->
                <div>
                <img src="images/shirt1.gif" style="height="300"; width="150";"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="font-size:14pt">Balloon</p>
                    <p>Price: €25</p>
                    <p style="font-size:12pt">Amount:</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div>
            <textarea type="amount" id="Balloonamount" rows="1" cols="6" style="overflow:hidden"><?php echo $amount;?></textarea>
            <input align="right" type="button" value="ADD" id="btn1" /> <!-- style="width:30px" --> 
            <script>
            document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                addProduct("Balloon", document.getElementById('Balloonamount').innerHTML);
            });
            </script>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>Cart</h1>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cart" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="einheit" width=20 align="right"></th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                    <th field="delete" width=20 align="right">X</th> <!--here the delete button -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
        <input type="button" value="Delete" width=auto align="center" id="deletebtn" onclick="deleteProduct()">
        <input type="button" value="Reset" width=auto align="right" id="resetbtn" onclick="">
            <script>
            document.getElementById('resetbtn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                if (confirm("Sure?") == true) {
                $('#cart').datagrid('loadData', {"total":0,"rows":[]});
                totalCost = 0;
                $('div.cart .total').html('Total: â‚¬'+0);
                }
            });
            </script>
        </div>
        <p class="total"><b>Total: â‚¬0</b></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not for nothing, it's clear from your code above that you do not have a firm grasp on how to use `jQuery` selectors and functions. These may help you a bit there: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/  https://www.impressivewebs.com/jquery-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: ty a lot this will help a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

First we add a `td` with a delete button in it to each row in the html table

Then we can attach a listener to the `#table` element (the element with `id="table"`). This listener listens for clicks on descendants of `#table` that have the class `delete-table, when one is clicked, we take the button and find the closest` tr` to the button (going up the DOM tree) and we remove it.

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z22NU/716/)

```js
 
$('#table').on('click','.delete-row',function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     // $(this) is the button
     
});
```

```css
td {border: 1px #DDD solid; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer;}

.selected {
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><button class="delete-row">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><button class="delete-row">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
        <td>1 000€</td>
        <td>1 200€</td>
        <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>F138</td>
        <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        <td><button class="delete-row">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: with your little example it works but i dont have a static table... the user is adding more and more rows while adding products into his "cart"... so the buttons must be added every time too

Answer (score 0):

heres an example of how I've done something similar in the past...

basically i add a delete button to each row programatically:

```
// ADD A DELETE BUTTON ON EACH ROW
$('td').each(function(i, val){ 
    $('td').eq(i).prepend('<span class="deleteButton">Delete</span>')
});
```

Then any time one of these buttons is clicked, we delete the corresponding (parent) row:

```
// WHEN DELETE BUTTON IS CLICKED REMOVE THE TABLE ROW
$(document).on('mousedown', '.deleteButton', function(){
     $('tr').eq($('.deleteButton').index(this)).remove();
})
```

heres [working demo](http://codepen.io/Lsad/pen/vxqMxb).

Comment: You should bind to `$('#table')` instead of `$(document)` since it's much closer to the target elements in the DOM. And `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` would be far more efficient than starting with the index of the button you already have.

Comment: Actually, `$('#table tr').find('td:eq(0)').prepend('<button class="deleteButton">Delete</button>')` would make it even better ;)

Comment: i tried this out but i cant include this into my code... maybe you have an idea of how to use my .selected {
      background-color: brown;
      color: #FFF;
  } instead of adding a button on every row... so i can use one button to remove all selected rows?